# How does a new user (on Drupal Answers) ask a question which involves lots of detail?

Tags: support, questions

I'm trying to pose questions with sufficient detail. I deleted my first try. My second try is below but you see I haven't sufficient privilege to post links or pictures:
[Need help with Views and Glossary](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/195979/need-help-with-views-and-glossary)
So I followed someone's suggestion and copied the pictures together. Here is my next try:
[Need help with Views and Glossary](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/196045/need-help-with-views-and-glossary-revised)

Then I got a response asking for screenshots of my system, but as you must realize, I haven't got sufficient privilege to include them as part of my intial question. I couldn't find any posts on Drupal Answers about how to add information (clarification) for the original question, so I included my screenshots as an answer (although it wasn't an answer at all). My post because they thought I was asking a new question.

In my original query I deleted something which I thought gave me the answer, but I was wrong. In trying to amend my answer-which-was-wrong, my question was closed.

**Trying to circumvent the restrictions placed on new users to Drupal Answers** has taken hours of work. AND I'm not posting my questions properly, which will probably get me suspended.

Advice please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not a moderator, but I do hang out in the review queue from time to time. So let me sketch you the perspective of a reviewer (Drupal police as you stated). And just to be sure, I did not review any of your questions.

We try to keep the site as clean and as relevant as possible. This Q&A, not a forum. There is no such things as threads and follow-up posts here and we like to keep it like that. If a question is posted as an answer (or in your case; follow-up on the question), it will get flagged as "not an answer" because it isn't one. This helps to keep questions and answers relevant for the poster and other people coming in here via searches.

Yet I understand it must be frustrating to see your attempts for good content be closed faster than you can create them. You try to do good and stick to the rules, but, please understand, so do we. We deal with spam posts on a daily basis and (I suppose) this is the main reason a user has to earn some privileges first so the system knows it is a trusted user.

**My advice**

Asking for screenshots is quite a common request and in fact happens so much, I doubt people (including myself) actually realize not every user is allowed to do so. What most new users do, is upload the images to a third party image sharing service (there is plenty of those) and then provide the URL's to them in your question. A reviewer might even edit the post for you and embed the images. That is the best way to comply with the site policies.

If you create good content you should be gathering some up votes in a short amount of time and your limitations will vanish :)

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful remarks, @Neograph734. As it happens, I am only allowed 2 links per post, so even uploading images to another site wouldn't help me. Someone else suggested that I edit my original content to ask my follow up question, which is what I shall try today. I don't think that provides helpful information to anyone who comes after me, but I understand that the site must have rules to combat spam. Thanks again for taking the time to post an answer.

Comment: I suppose you can paste them as text? or remove the `h` from `http` if you explain in the post the link is not clickable because of system limitations nobody would mind. Most of us are nice people here :) Good luck and I hope you will have better experiences in the future!

Comment: The OP does just need to gain 5 points, to be able to use more than two links. He should not suffer too long for this limitation. +1 for a good explanation of how Stack Exchange sites work.